# Change AppIcon at build time in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, imagemagick, xcode9

I use a script to generate app icon at build time (just add "dev" title for debug mode). That's pretty easy using ImageMagick and Ghostscript (a lot of examples in google). Everything was ok before I started to use new Xcode 9. Now, I can see updated icons on MyAppName.app file but simulator/device shows AppIcon from assets. 
Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: I have a problem with my script, i get a error when compilance, "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when Xcode9 builds an app it now copies app icons from asset catalog into a private format and does not use app icon files from bundle directly. This might be related to new iOS11 feature where you can change app icons at runtime.

There is a simple fix. What you have to do is change your app icons *directly* in asset catalog so must do 2 changes in your build setup:

**1. step - update run script phase**

Update your "generate icon" run script build phase so that updated icons are not copied to target bundle but instead icons are changed in asset catalog. Here is an example of my generate script, please notice `target_path=$base_path` line:

```
function processIcon() {
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    base_file=$1
    base_path=`find ${SRCROOT}/Cards/Assets.xcassets -name $base_file`

    if [[ ! -f ${base_path} || -z ${base_path} ]]; then
    echo "failed to find base_path for $base_file"
    return -1;
    fi

    target_file=`echo $base_file`

    #this is the change
    target_path=$base_path

    echo $target_path

    width=`identify -format %w ${base_path}`

    convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x40 caption:"${version} (${build}) ${commit}" ${base_path} +swap -gravity south -composite ${target_path}
}
```

**2. step - change order of build phases**

you must change order of your build phases so that "Generate Icon" build phase is ordered *before* "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase:
[image: changed order of build phases]

Original idea and script code is from [Krzysztof Zabłocki's blog post](http://merowing.info/2013/03/overlaying-application-version-on-top-of-your-icon/).

Comment: could you set the full script

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the way how to fix script, so I changed approach.
What I did:

1. added new variable BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX (Build Settings / + / user-defined settings).
2. I have few configurations (qa, release, development), so I just updated "Bundle Identifier" in Info.plist. I've appended ${BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX}, so now my development configuration has bundle id like com.my.app.dev, qa - com.my.app.qa, etc.
3. Next, I added one more set with icons (with "dev" label). And I set AppIcon name in the same way as bundle id - I appended ${BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX}.
   As the result I have different sets of app icons for each configuration.

Below is the link to great tutorial which I followed
Take a look at following [link](https://engineering.circle.com/different-app-icons-for-your-ios-beta-dev-and-release-builds-af4d209cdbfd), solution works great.

Answer (score 1):

**Support Xcode 9**

check full example here
https://github.com/dimohamdy/IconOverlaying

**Full Script**

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin:

convertPath=`which convert`
gsPath=`which gs`

if [[ ! -f ${convertPath} || -z ${convertPath} ]]; then
  convertValidation=true;
else
  convertValidation=false;
fi

if [[ ! -f ${gsPath} || -z ${gsPath} ]]; then
  gsValidation=true;
else
  gsValidation=false;
fi

if [[ "$convertValidation" = true || "$gsValidation" = true ]]; then
  echo "WARNING: Skipping Icon versioning, you need to install ImageMagick and ghostscript (fonts) first, you can use brew to simplify process:"

  if [[ "$convertValidation" = true ]]; then
    echo "brew install imagemagick"
  fi
  if [[ "$gsValidation" = true ]]; then
    echo "brew install ghostscript"
  fi
exit 0;
fi

version=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`
build_num=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`

# Check if we are under a Git or Hg repo
if [ -d .git ] || git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    commit=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
    branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
else
    commit=`hg identify -i`
    branch=`hg identify -b`
fi;

#SRCROOT=..
#CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.
#UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=.

#commit="3783bab"
#branch="master"
#version="3.4"
#build_num="9999"

shopt -s extglob
build_num="${build_num##*( )}"
shopt -u extglob
caption="${version} ($build_num)\n${branch}\n${commit}"
echo $caption

function abspath() { pushd . > /dev/null; if [ -d "$1" ]; then cd "$1"; dirs -l +0; else cd "`dirname \"$1\"`"; cur_dir=`dirs -l +0`; if [ "$cur_dir" == "/" ]; then echo "$cur_dir`basename \"$1\"`"; else echo "$cur_dir/`basename \"$1\"`"; fi; fi; popd > /dev/null; }

function processIcon() {
    base_path=$1

     echo base_path

    #this is the change
    target_path=$base_path


    width=`identify -format %w ${base_path}`
    height=`identify -format %h ${base_path}`

    band_height=$((($height * 47) / 100))
    band_position=$(($height - $band_height))
    text_position=$(($band_position - 3))
    point_size=$(((13 * $width) / 100))

    echo "Image dimensions ($width x $height) - band height $band_height @ $band_position - point size $point_size"

    #
    # blur band and text
    #
    convert ${base_path} -blur 10x8 /tmp/blurred.png
    convert /tmp/blurred.png -gamma 0 -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,$band_position,$width,$height" /tmp/mask.png
    convert -size ${width}x${band_height} xc:none -fill 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)' -draw "rectangle 0,0,$width,$band_height" /tmp/labels-base.png
    convert -background none -size ${width}x${band_height} -pointsize $point_size -fill white -gravity center -gravity South caption:"$caption" /tmp/labels.png

    convert ${base_path} /tmp/blurred.png /tmp/mask.png -composite /tmp/temp.png

    rm /tmp/blurred.png
    rm /tmp/mask.png

    #
    # compose final image
    #
    filename=New${base_file}
    convert /tmp/temp.png /tmp/labels-base.png -geometry +0+$band_position -composite /tmp/labels.png -geometry +0+$text_position -geometry +${w}-${h} -composite "${target_path}"

    # clean up
    rm /tmp/temp.png
    rm /tmp/labels-base.png
    rm /tmp/labels.png

    echo "Overlayed ${target_path}"
}






    if [ $CONFIGURATION = "Release" ]; then
       cp  $SRCROOT/$PROJECT_NAME/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icons/*.png "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/"
      echo "Exit"
      exit 0
    fi
    

if [ -d "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icons/" ] 
then
    echo "Directory exists." 
    # get original icon to copy to assets
       cp  $SRCROOT/$PROJECT_NAME/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icons/*.png "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/"
else
    # copy orgin to AppIcon
    rsync -rv  --include '*.png' --exclude '*' "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/" "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icons/"
fi


for entry in "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset"/*.png
do
  processIcon "$entry"
done
```

Comment: I can't get past the validation, it returns the WARNING, however I have imagemagick and ghostscript correctly installed, any ideas?